# PHPUnit in a legacy environment

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm starting to setup PHPUnit (v4.8) to be used in my 'legacy' code (it's not so legacy, but it have bad programming practices).

The structure of my folders is as follows

```
/home
  -phpunit.xml
  /folder1
  /folder2
  /folder3
  /vendor
  /tests
   -Test1.php
  /includes
   -functions.php
   /libs
    -User.php
    -TableClass.php
    ....
```

**functions.php**

`<?php 
//require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/home/vendor/autoload.php" ;
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/home/includes/libs/table_classes/User.php" ;
?>`

I have commented that line, because I think composer automatically loads it. **Question 1**, Am I Rigth? (because phpunit get automatically recognized inside my Test class...)

**Test1.php**

```
<?php

class Test1 extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testSomething()
  {
    // $something = getColNameByStatusId(1);
    $this->assertEquals(1,2);
  }
}
?>
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="includes/functions.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="Test1" >
        <directory>./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

Then I Execute `phpunit` in command line

My `functions.php` works fine in my code, of course with no composer integration, but when It's loaded with phpunit it 'breaks', I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/includes/libs/table_classes/User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\home\includes\functions.php on line 18
```

I think I'm missing the 'loading' stuff for phpunit. My code doesn't use namespaces and PSR-0 neither PSR-4.

**Question 2**- How to properly load files in this case?

**My goal** is to load `functions.php` then it will load all other 'table' classes for doing my tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with `__DIR__` and adjusted the paths accordingly, and everything worked fine.

PHPUnit does not set `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so It was not finding my files. Apache's do that. So the CLI of PHPUnit couldn't find it.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You could add in the bootstrap file $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'Something'; which would prevent you having to adjust your code

Comment: @exussum Yes, I've analysed and __DIR__ It's really better. Thanks for your suggestion, I've setup some variables in bootstrap for _SERVER anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed dir is better. Depends on size of code base though

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to start using PHPUnit by running

```
phpunit --generate-configuration
```

and follow some simple questions.

To autoload `'functions.php'` and other table `'classes'`, you may try via composer.json autoload.

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Model\\": "libs/"
  }
}
```

Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84j61_aI0q8) with autoload for your reference.

Comment: I've tried that solution, but for my project needs, it's better leave as it Is